# Syntactical sugar for Doxygen to link a MonoBehaviour with Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, doxygen

We've just added the wonderful `Doxygen` to our project, and thus far we love it, specifically with the `Dot` visual graphs turned up to the max.

One of the particular areas we like is when you're properly able to track where some services are created, so you can best document the flow of certain areas, like:

[image]

This is an area of the initial entry flow into a mobile app, and we have a central location through which you access all the other services we have available.  This central location is initialised, as shown here in `SMAppServicesMonoBehaviour`.

What isn't shown, unfortunately is the "creation point" of `SMAppServicesMonoBehaviour`.  The reason for this is the way you create `MonoBehaviour`s in `Unity3D`.  You can create one in the Editor by simply attaching a script to a `GameObject`, or similarly in code, you attach a script to a `GameObject` with `AddComponent`,

```
new GameObject("SMAppServices").AddComponent<SMAppServicesMonoBehaviour>();
```

This means that that link between where `SMAppServicesMonoBehaviour` is actually created / instantiated from isn't tracked.

Hence the question, is there any syntactical way I can attach some meta information for `Doxygen` to this code block to state something along the lines of above, "We are touching / accessing SMAppServicesMonoBehaviour.Start"?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in C with a table of function pointers.  Doxygen couldn't see that the routine accessing the table would call those functions.  I discovered that if I move the declaration of the table as a local static to the function, Doxygen would then see the function calls (or better said: would know that a call was possible).

```
void func() {
    funcptr calltable[] = { foo, bar, foobar };
    ...
}
```

Your scenario might just be too abstract though.  You might try other trickery in the code but I don't recommend to do anything complicated; It defeats the purpose of having readable code.

A thought might be to suggest to the Doxygen team new commands `\calls` and `\calledby` to explicitly make the connections.  But I don't think Doxygen supports documentation for specific instantiations.

The code doing the calling is very generic, a template member of a generic class?  If it were to be connected in a call graph you might have a confusing fan-out of all possible references, when really you only want to show that `SMAppServices` is connected, and ideally only the specific instantiation based on `SMAppServicesMonoBehaviour`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Michael, I'll try it out and mark as accepted if I get it working. As for the "generic class" bit, this is more for documenting the startup flow for a mobile app. What calls where, at what time, when things are ready, and just on general, getting that nicely down in the docs.